# What is this error: Missing stack map in ....?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I created lib for my blackberry java app (jar file). But it isn't work.
com.myapp.MyManager: Error!: Missing stack map in: getInstance at label: 31 
What is this?
If i copy package of my lib to my blackberry app,  it works well. But I need have lib.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to preverify the jar file manually. you can do the following to preverify the jar.

```
execute the following command: 
 preverify -classpath "JDE_PATH_HERE\lib\net_rim_api.jar" "your_jar_filename"
```

Read more: http://getablogger.blogspot.com/2009/09/how-to-include-external-jar-file-in.html#ixzz1iTh6g1SF

You can try this [link](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11938/Preverify_a_BlackBerry_Java_Application_512512_11.jsp) as well .It has instructions on how to do it.

Comment: I did so. but I have an error: Error preverifing class com.myapp.MYIOFile, java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

Comment: copy the jar to c:/dev folder and then try

Comment: I am also getting the same error: java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError