# NoClassDefFoundError while preverify the jar files in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, eclipse-plugin, preverify

I have also asked this question on the BlackBerry support forums, under the thread "[NoClassDefFoundError while preverify the jar files in BlackBerry](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/NoClassDefFoundError-while-preverify-the-jar-files-in-BlackBerry/td-p/2116547)"

I am adding a library files(jar files) in my BlackBerry Project and and try to run it. But it is giving me the below error : **Error!: Missing stack map at label 77**. So i try to find out the issue and find this link: [Preverify Link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Missing-stack-map-at-label/ta-p/445978)

So i tried to fix this issue using preverifier. As i am using BlackBerry eclipse plugin, i have tried in this way:

1. Copy the jar file in the bin folder of my eclipse 6.0 plugins (eclipse-SDK-3.5.2-win32\eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.29\components\bin)
2. Execute the following command in the command line:

   ```
    preverify -classpath "<path to 6.0.0.29 SDK>\net_rim_api.jar" "ArcotOTP-Lib-Java-Test-2.0.0.jar"
   ```

But after running this line, i am getting the below error:

```
Error preverifying class Mypackage.API$1
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: Mypackage/Test
```

Comment: I tried in this way..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723540/what-is-this-error-missing-stack-map-in                                       But not working for me..

Answer (score 2):

BlackBerry devices are running on the Java-ME platform, so you can't use modern java features. Typical Java jar files these days use newer features that are not backward compatible with the Java-ME platform.  Some projects do go out of the way to be backward compatible, like [Bouncy Castle](http://bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html).  But that is rare.

This question, duplicated on the BlackBerry forums, was also answered on the BlackBerry forums, which I will capture here:

simon_hain:

> and is it a j2me library?

Arindam Mukherjee:

> No it is java library..all classes are basically java classes. The same library i am using for android also and it is working fine fro me..

simon_hain:

> BlackBerry uses J2ME as a base, Android uses J2SE.
>   You cannot use an Android library on BlackBerry unless you re-compile it (and resolve all the errors due to missing reflection, lists etc)